Proving equivalence of an alternative definition for $BPP$ class
I want to prove that the following definition also defines $BPP$ and is equivalent to the standard definition:
A language $L$ is in $BPP$ if there's a polynomial time Probabilistic Turing Machine $M$, such that for some fixed $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$, $0<\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2<1$, we have
$x \notin L \implies Pr[M(x,r) \ accepts] \leq \epsilon_1$, and
$x \in L \implies Pr[M(x,r) \ accepts] \geq \epsilon_2$,
where Probabilistic Turing Machine just means a Turing Machine with an extra read only tape called randomness tape, and $r$ is the randomness tape.
This is almost equivalent to the standard definition, except that it doesn't require $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2=1$, and it doesn't require that $\epsilon_1<\frac{1}{2}$. I think I should somehow show that $0<\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2<1$ implies these two conditions, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

You can't show $0 < \varepsilon_1 < \varepsilon_2 < 1$ implies the other two conditions since, e.g., $\varepsilon_1 = 0.1, \varepsilon_2 = 0.2$ violates $\varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2 = 1$.
Here's a hint. Imagine you have a probabilistic TM $P$ that satisfies the conditions you mentioned for some $\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2$. You want to construct a probabilistic TM $P'$ that satisfies the conditions for the usual definition of BPP (i.e., always runs in polynomial time and has false-positive and false-negative probabilities at most $\varepsilon$ for some $0 < \varepsilon < \frac12$.). How will running $P$ a bunch of times help you?
For example, suppose you know $\varepsilon_1 = 0.1$ and $\varepsilon_2 = 0.2$, and you run $P$ many many times and found that it accepts $30\%$ of the time. What should you do? What should you do if it accepts $8\%$ of the time?
